# How do I write a function that loops through all lowercase to number mappings?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I need to write a function that maps each of the 26 lowercase alphabetic characters to a single digit number in [0, 9]. I need this function to generate all possible combinations (26^10 of them). I know of a way to write this with recursion, but I would like to do it without recursion, and I'm not sure what the algorithm should look like.

Could someone provide an algorithm for this without recursion?

Comment: As Jerry's answer points out, attempting to compute all of the possible mappings will take way too long, even if the code doesn't do anything with the mappings. But if you want to code it anyways, then the what you do is create an array of 26 elements. Initialize the array with all zeros. On each iteration, increment the least significant element (e.g. the element for 'Z'). If the result is 10, set it back to 0, and increment the next element ('Y'). Keep incrementing until either you reach an element that doesn't roll over, or until the 'A' rolls over. When 'A' rolls over, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here is some code that prints the representation of each function:

```
for idx in range(10 ** 26):
    print(f"function {idx}")
    for letter in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
        # f(letter) = 1 + (idx % 10)
        print(f"\tf({chr(letter)}) = {1 + (idx % 10)}")
        idx //= 10
```

You'll notice that this code will take a very, **very** long time to run. There are 10 options for what 'a' maps to, 10 options for what 'b' maps to, etc., so there are 10^26 possible mappings. Generally a computer will only do around 10^9 operations in a second, so doing anything with these mappings will not be tractable.

Comment: The rule of thumb 'there are pi seconds in a nano-century' is good to better than 1%. Using this, the 10^18 seconds to spend 1 nanosecond on each mapping amounts to more than 3*10^10 years, or longer than the age of the universe!